# What will be the MAC address for same type of BLE devices , different or same in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, mac-address, bluetooth-gatt

I have a BLE device with mac address `88:5B:0F:07:E7:70` (as I'm getting in android app). In my app I'm scanning devices with a specific type(In my case BLE lock), but there can be multiple type of devices in environment, but I have to scan only for locks. So what will be the mac address for all ble locks from same manufacturer,it would be same as `88:5B:0F:07:E7:70` or different. Unfortunately I have only one BLE lock that's why I couldn't find the solution. It would be appreciable if anyone can help me out this.

Comment: See: [Is it possible to find the manufacturer of a BLE device from it's mac address?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/151768/90202)

Comment: @ Morrison Chang, this will provide the manufacturer name only, I want to know if address will be same or not??

Comment: Actually it would depend on the manufacturer of the BLE device and what part of the scanning process you are in: http://microchipdeveloper.com/wireless:ble-link-layer-address and https://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-technology-protecting-your-privacy

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of solving this is to check the advertising data. A certain kind of device advertises a particular GATT service or manufacturer data. That is what you should filter on.

Comment: Yes I'm getting a byte array as data in `onLeScan()` method but I don't know how to use this to get the information like lock state, door state, battery level etc.

Comment: If you use the new API provided by Lollipop and forward, it will parse the scan record.

Comment: Use this api: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html and you get it parsed.